# Nautilus-Open-Terminal tries to open ZSH instead of bash

Tags: bash, nautilus, zsh

I recently tried zsh as a shell but didn't like it much. Then removed it and I still continue to use bash.

When I was using bash, I had this cool script 'nautilus-open-terminal' which lets you open a terminal in the directory you are currently in, with right-click to an empty area in nautilus.

However, after removing zsh from my computer, I noticed that nautilus-open-terminal was not working. When I press 'Open In Terminal', the terminal was being opened for a split second and immediately closing itself.

To avoid the terminal to close itself, I set the terminal's preferences as
[When Command Exits: Hold the Terminal Open]

[image]

As you can see in the above link, Hold The Terminal Open is selected

And after doing this, now I could see the problem. When I pressed 'Open In Terminal', I saw this screen:

[image]

Nautilus-Open-Terminal tries to use zsh

---

To conclude, **my nautilus-open-terminal tries to use zsh instead of my bash; therefore it crashes since i do not have a /bin/zsh file anymore**.

This problem of 'nautilus-open-terminal immediately closes itself' is quite common as far as I can see. However, from the posts I have seen, people talk about different issues that cause the same problem that I have.

Now comes my question:

**How do I reconfigure my nautilus-open-terminal so that it will use the bash instead of zsh?**

- And yes, I tried purged remove and installing it again.

Thank you for your interests.

Comment: what's the output of `echo $SHELL`

Comment: It IS indeed /bin/zsh.
How do I change that?

* Btw, when i used chsh to change my shell, I was able to do it and now, chsh command still shows me /bin/bash.

Interesting.

Comment: That's exactly what I did actually. However, after doing that, when i echo $SHELL, I still see /bin/zsh.

Comment: just log-out and log-in

Comment: Wow, thank you.  It worked. Now I feel a bit dumb actually :).

I don't know how ubuntu works in these situations. I felt like it should be perceived by the OS and be updated immediately.

Thanks again, Ron.

Comment: @Ron It's your answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `bash` your default shell by:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

then log-out and log-in. Now, `nautilus-open-terminal` will use `bash`.

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, guys. I pointed Ron's answer to be the one and upvoted.